# Parse string into another data type in Haskell

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell

Recently I have been trying to create in Haskell a regex interpretor. What I did was create a new data type with all possible constructors (for sequence, `*`, `^`, intervals, etc) and then define a matcher function. It works wonders but my problem is that I have to convert the input (the String, for example `"a(b*)(c|d)ef"`) to my data type (`"Seq (Sym a) (Seq (Rep Sym b) (Seq (Or Sym c Sym d) Sym ef))"`). I am having trouble with this part of the problem (I tried creating a new data type, a parsing tree, but I failed completely). Any ideas on how I could solve it?

Comment: In case you're not building this just for fun, there is also Text.Regex

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec: I don't know its details, but it's a really good library for parsing... playing with it also teaches you many things about monads.

Answer (score 8):

The canonical approach is to use a parser combinator library, such as [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec).
Parser combinator libraries (like parser generators) let you write descriptions of your grammar, yielding a parser from strings to tokens in that language.

You simply have to encode your grammar as a Parsec function.

As an example, see this previous SO question: [Using Parsec to parse regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020254/using-parsec-to-parse-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Jani Hartikainen: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use Text.Regex

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use Parsec and see what I manage to do

Answer (score 4):

That's an interesting article (a play) on the implementation of regular expressions:

[A Play on Regular Expressions](http://sebfisch.github.com/haskell-regexp/regexp-play.pdf)